# Keep common headers and use across many services in angular 2/4

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have several service in my app such as `AuthenticateService` , `UserService` to request data from the API.

There are some common headers which user in most of the service functions such as `authentication token` and `Content-Type header`.
I want to keep these headers inside a single class and use them in services when requesting data.

I tried create an `custom export class` and by defining functions inside it to get these but it gives several errors.
Angular 2 / 4

Class to access from services

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 


import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class MainService {

    commonHeaders(){
        let headers = new Headers({  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        return headers; 
    }

    AuthorizedRequestCommonHeaders() {
        let headers = new Headers({  
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + (localStorage.getItem('auth_token')) ); 
        return headers;
    } 

}
```

I tried to access like below 
AuthenticationService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

import { MainService } from './main-service';  

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  login(email: string, password: string) {
    let headers = this.MainService.commonHeaders();
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers
    });

    let postData = {  
        email: email,
        password: password  
    }

    return this.http.post(this.oauthUrl, JSON.stringify(postData) , options)
        .map((response: Response) => { 
            let result = response.json(); 
            if (result && result.token) { 
                localStorage.setItem('auth_token', JSON.stringify(result.token)); 
            }
        });

}
```

Error message

> Property 'commonHeaders' does not exist on type 'MainService'.

Comment: Please provide full code for `AuthenticationService` (do you inject `MainService` there?). Also please check if you added `MainService` and `AuthenticationService` to your `NgModule#providers` so injector is aware of those classes. Also please provide error message you are getting, as "NOT WORKING" means nothing. Moreover, please consider to use `HttpClient` api (if you still use old `HttpModule`). It provides api for having Interceptors, so you can keep all request-related stuff in 1 place and create conditions/convention for including specific headers based on other request parameters.

Comment: @A.Tim . Question updated with full code. Added to provides in NgModule but still no luck.

Comment: So like I said, you do not inject `MainService` into `AuthenticationService`. do `AuthenticationService{constructor(private mainService: MainService){} login(){let headers = this.mainService.commonHeaders(); ...} }`

Answer (score 0):

Made common function which we can use anywhere by importing it

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';     
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class MainService {



    AuthorizedRequestCommonHeaders() {
        let headers = commonHeaders();
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + (localStorage.getItem('auth_token')) ); 
        return headers;
    } 

}

export function commonHeaders(){ //keep this is main service or any other but make sure to provide proper path
            let headers = new Headers({  
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            });
            return headers; 
        }
```

AuthenticationService.ts

```
import { commonHeaders } from './main-service'; 

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  login(email: string, password: string) {
    let headers = commonHeaders();
}
```

Comment: I changed it to a static function as you mentioned but still same

Comment: you can write interceptor https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-all-requests-or-responses . checkout setting header section.

Comment: @Hashan: Done some modification please check now